# Collapse Output In VS Code Jupyter Notebook into Scrollable Window

Tags: python, dataframe, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to show the output such as a very long data-frame in a scrollable window in VS Code Jupyter Notebook?

I am aware that pressing letter "o" allows you to collapse all output. But having the scrollable window is still preferable as it allows you to check the output while referring to other windows.

I also checked this [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/10695) but couldn't get it work.

Comment: The update [Notebooks are getting revamped!](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/notebooks-are-getting-revamped/) is for [**VSCode Insiders**](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/), we're using VS Code and now this funciton is not support in it.

Comment: A workaround for this is to add a print statement  at the beginning or end of  the cell output (e.g. `print('foo')`). This will trigger the scrollable window.

Comment: Hi @Davis thanks for your contribution, that's amazing! Please feel free  to add as an answer :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the comments, a workaround to trigger the scrollable window is to add a print statement to the cell output. For example `print("foo")` at the beginning or end of a cell.

Answer (score 7):

There is a beta feature for scrolling now. Simply add `"notebook.experimental.outputScrolling": true` to `settings.json`.

Comment: Meanwhile (VSCode 1.79.0 and newer) the feature is called:
`"notebook.output.scrolling": true`

Comment: @burn4science `"notebook.output.scrolling": true` does not work for me. I've had it active for months, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 4):

Go to setting and type notebook.output.scrolling. there you can eanble scrolling
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8M4W.png)