# How to control result size when using jupyter on vsc and how to search for words in result

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm currently using Jupytor Notebook on VSC. I found it very uncomfortable when very long result come out because I have to scroll down a long way to go the the next cell, like shown in the picture.

[image]

So I was wondering if there is a way to make the result like the original Jupyter Notebook, where they have a separate scroll for the result as shown below.

[image]

As an additional question, anyone know how to search for certain words in the result on VSC? ctrl+f only searches for words in the coding cells and not the result.

Answer (score 1):

<s>A work around for the scroll wheel if you don’t want to collapse the code is to add a print statement to the beginning and end of the code block as mentioned in [Collapse Output in VS Code Jupyter Into Scrollable Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64795881/collapse-output-in-vs-code-jupyter-notebook-into-scrollable-window). I have not been at my computer to test this and this post is from a year ago, so I’m not sure if this solution is still working.</s> **EDIT:** This solution is no longer working keep an eye on the linked issue for the resolution.

This was also brought up as an issue on GitHub and it was closed saying they have no plans to work on it currently.
[#118117](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/118117)

As for the searching in outputs, this is an open issue currently on GitHub: [#94239](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/94239)

Comment: Thanks for answering! I tried adding print() at beginning & end of cell but doesn't seem to work. I guess I'll just have to use the text editor to open the output and search from there...

Comment: Ya, they must have added something that negated that. Keep an eye on that issue I linked for the solution. I will make an edit to note the print solution is no longer working. Please upvote and mark it as correct to bring visibility to the linked issue.

Answer (score 0):

Scrollable output regions would be handled in VS Code core. This function has not been decided on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/144111) at present

For your additional question, I think the filter feature in the search widget might be what you're looking for - you can include outputs with that.

[image]