Restricting the size of output of a code-cell when using Jupyter extension in VS Code
Even when editing the setting of VS Code called "notebook.output.scrolling" to "true", the output of a code-cell in a notebook (i.e. file with extension ".ipynb") does not get restricted, except when using the function "print(...)" to create output.

If you for example try using either:

the function "display(...)" from "IPython.display" to display a pandas.DataFrame, or

making a plot using "matplotlib.pyplot" and displaying it in the output,

then the size of the code-cell output is not restricted and scrollable, but stretches all the way until the whole element (either the pandas.DataFrame, or the plot) is displayed.

Is there an option in VS Code which will allow its user to restrict the size of a code-cell output, not matter how the output is created (i.e. no matter if the output is generated using the function "display(...)", if it is a plot, if it is using the function "print(...)")?
Note: There is a similar issue in StackOverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64795881/collapse-output-in-vs-code-jupyter-notebook-into-scrollable-window, but the person who created the question was searching for the option "notebook.output.scrolling" which does not solve the problem which I am facing.
I checked if the changing the setting called "notebook.output.scrolling" to "true" would solve the problem, but it did not (although I think that this option should restrict the size of the code-cell output, no matter how the output is created).


for the plots you can simply set its size using plt.figure(figsize=(x, y)). You can adjust its height and width by playing around with the x and y values.

of course that you could restrict the size manually, but I am looking for a solution which would be aplicable to every type of output
